# Trying to show a component which is wrapped in ng-template, using BsModalService

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap

I am trying to display a component using `ngx-bootstrap` BsModalService. I am trying to provide input data using template, and then my goal is to subscribe to specific Output when closing the modal.

The problem is that the modalRef.content is null.

**html**

```
<ng-template #myModal>
  <my-component [data]="data$ | async">
  </my-component>
</ng-template>
```

**ts**

```
constructor(
  private readonly api: ApiService,
  private readonly modalService: BsModalService,
) {
}

@ViewChild('myModal', { read: TemplateRef }) myModal;

onClick(){
  this.api.getData().subscribe(data => {
    this.data$.next(data);

    const modal: BsModalRef = this.modalService.show(this.myModal);      
    const comp = (<MyComponent>modal.content);
    // comp is null
  });
}
```

My guess is that wrapping the component in `ng-template` makes it inaccessible for BsModalService. Is this scenario feasible at all?

Answer (score 0):

That is per [documentation](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals#bs-modal-ref)

> content
>   Type: any
>   Reference to a component inside the modal. **Null** if modal's been created with TemplateRef

If you want to access the contents of a template, you can use `@ContentChild`, but you have to change your code to this:

```
constructor(
  private readonly api: ApiService,
  private readonly modalService: BsModalService,
) {
}

@ContentChild(MyComponent) myComp: MyComponent;

onClick(){
  this.api.getData().subscribe(data => {
    this.data$.next(data);

    this.modalService.show(this.myModal);  

    // not sure if it's already available here, or you need to wrap it in a setTimeout...    
    const comp = this.myComp;
  });
}
```

Comment: I am getting undefined even with `setTimeout`. I am afraid that `ContentChild` or `ViewChild` will not be available within `ng-template` until the template is somehow rendered

Comment: Looks like there is no way (and no use) to use html template here. It works just perfect when I removed inputs and invoked `this.modalService.show(MyComp, {initialState: ...input values here...})`. Of course, `MyComp` has to be an `entryComponent`. Thanks for reminding me of ContentChildren though - I tend to forget this decorator!